# Sum two bytes in Python/Micropython

Tags: python, esp32, micropython

I would like to sum two bytes in Python, Micropython in the easiest way possible

I'm. working on some code for University. It simply has to send data to address shifted by 'mask' eg.

```py
 addrs = b'\x10'
 mask = b'\x01'
 finaladdrs = addrs + mask #should be b'\x11'
 machine.send(finaladdrs, somevalue)
```

I've already tried converting to int, but it doesn't work properly. Converting to a string requires a lot of processing.

Comment: What should be the value of `finaladdrs` if `addrs = b'\x01'` and `mask = b'\x01'`?

Comment: What is the problem with the code you've shown?

Answer (score 3):

Elements of a byte string are integers:

```
>>> addrs = b'\x10'
>>> mask = b'\x01'
>>> addrs[0] + mask[0]
17
```

Back to bytes:

```
>>> bytes([addrs[0] + mask[0]])
b'\x11'
```

This can be convenient for iterating over byte data, such as generating a checksum:

```
>>> data = bytes([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> data
b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05'
>>> data += bytes([sum(data) & 0xFF]) # bytes data must be 0-255, hence mask
>>> data
b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x0f'
```

To limit conversions from integer lists to bytes and vice versa, you can use a mutable bytearray:

```
>>> addrs = bytearray(b'\x10')
>>> mask = b'\x01'
>>> addrs[0] += mask[0]
>>> addrs
bytearray(b'\x11')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are flexible in assigning `addrs` and `mask`  to start with `0b` instead of `b'\x'`, here is a solution:

```
addrs = 0b10  
mask = 0b01 
finaladdrs = bin(addrs + mask)
print(finaladdrs)
```

output:

```
0b11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ord and chr for conversion

Code:

```
addrs = b'\x10'
mask = b'\x01'

finaladdrs = bytes(chr(ord(addrs) + ord(mask)), encoding='utf-8')
```

Output:

```
b'\x11'
```